# c - Make is only running 'gcc' with no parameters

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm learning how to use C and Make, but Make is making me tear my hair out. When I run make with all targets I've created it fails, running gcc with no parameters, **except** one of them randomly works just fine. Here is what happens when I try to build with most of the targets:

```
$ make strvector.o
gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [vector.o] Error 4
```

and when I run the one that works:

```
$ make word.o
gcc -Wall -g -ansi -pedantic -c -o word.o word.c
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -ansi -pedantic -c -o $@ $^
LD = gcc
LDFLAGS =

fw: fw.o vector.o hashtable.o strvector.o
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o fw vector.o hashtable.o strvector.o word.o

fw.o: fw.c vector.o hashtable.o strvector.o word.o
        $(CC) $(CFALGS)

vector.o: vector.c word.o
        $(CC) $(CFALGS)

hashtable.o: hashtable.c vector.o word.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

word.o: word.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

strvector.o: strvector.c
        $(CC) $(CFALGS)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why word.o builds fine but not anything else. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

--Edit-- I made a typo. Writing CFALGS instead of CFLAGS. not sure how I missed that one. Thanks guys!

Comment: Well, `CFALGS` is not defined, so it becomes the empty string.

Comment: You would be better off setting `CFLAGS=-Wall -g -ansi -pedantic` and not defining any rules.  Make is pretty good with implicit rules, and `-o ...` and the file to be operated on do *not* belong in CFLAGS.

Comment: You assigned CFLAGS, but you did not assign CFALGS.  It's a typo.

Comment: The command lines with `$(CC) $(CFLAGS)` don't have any filename arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You left out the filenames in the compilation commands.

```
strvector.o: strvector.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

`$@` gets replaced with the current target, `$<` is replaced with the current dependency.